# Efficient algorithm for converting a "pop list" into an "index list"

Tags: algorithm, list, big-o

Suppose I have a list of items:

```
[ A, B, C, D ]
```

and a "pop list":

```
[ 2, 0, 1, 0 ]
```

Let `f(x,p) = y` be a function that pops the indices `p` from `x` into a new list, `y`.

Using this process, you can compute

```
f([ A, B, C, D ], [ 2, 0, 1, 0 ]) = [ C, A, D, B ]
```

However, the cost of `f` is impractical, because it pops from a list and joins the remaining elements repeatedly.

It would be desirable to have an algorithm, `g`, to convert the pop list into a list of indices, such that

```
g(p) = [ 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

This would allow the new list to be constructed efficiently.

Is there an efficient algorithm, perhaps O(N), which could be used in implement `g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small snippet in JS to explain my idea. The algorithm is NOT O(N) but probably O(n^2). It doesn't need to execute `f` though. I am not 100% certain this works properly but if not this might serve as an idea to build upon.

You reverse your pop list and iterate it:

1. Add current element to new array
2. Check whether previously added elements are bigger or equal to current element.

   3. If true, increment the respective values.
3. Return newly filled array (reversed).

Rough sequence:

```
0 
0 1
0 1 0
1 2 0 (increment old values with >= 0)
1 2 0 2
1 3 0 2 (increment old values with >= 2)
```

```js
const data = [2, 0, 1, 0];

function popToIdx(popList) {
    let arr = [],
        tmp = [...popList].reverse(); // 0 1 0 2

    for (let i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = tmp[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (arr[j] >= tmp[i]) {
          arr[j] += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    return arr.reverse();
}

console.log(popToIdx(data)) // 2 0 3 1
```

It works the same with lists since adding a new element to the end is still only O(1) and the partial iteration for lists and arrays is the same, too.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I'm looking for. I also considered this... but wasn't sure it would hold for all cases. But seeing someone else come up with the same idea is validating. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to apply `f` to a list of indexes:

```
g(p) = f([0, 1, ... length(p)-1], p)
```

(assuming length(p) is the range of indexes.  Otherwise use the appropriate length, or dynamically grow it if necessary)

This is *O(n^2)*.  You can make it *O(n log n)* by storing `x` in an order statistic tree instead of a list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Comment: The goal is to avoid calling `f`.

Comment: Ah... but what you're asking to do is exactly like calling `f`, as you can see.  Maybe you just want to put `x` in an order statistic tree to make `f` faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I really just want to transform the pop list into the index list without using `f`. And I was surprised at how tricky it got.

Comment: The answer I marked as "accepted" answers the question I was asking. I did, however, also find the information in this answer really useful.